# Vscode debug breakpoint passed over

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, debugging, breakpoints, delve

I'm running the latest VScode 1.74.2, Golang 1.19.4, and the latest Go Tools on macOs Ventura 13.1.

Got a simple "Hello World" program with 2 breakpoints.  The 1st breakpoint is bypassed everytime.
It seems to be related to this specific golang clause below.  No matter where I put it and set the breakpoint at the **If** statement, the debugger shoots right past it to the next breakpoint and stops there.  Very confusing.

```
if runtime.GOOS != `darwin` {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, `only runs on macOS`)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
```

**Complete program:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    if runtime.GOOS != `darwin` {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, `only runs on macOS`)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(`Hello World!`)
}
```

A bug?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSEAo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtLY1.png)

I was expecting the debugger to stop at the 1st breakpoint at the **if** statement.

I turned on Verbose tracing, added a **fmt.Println** statement before the **if** statement and then set breakpoints on the 1st **fmt.Println** statement (line 19), the **if** statement (line 21) and the **fmt.Println** statement (line 26) following the **if** statement clause.  Then started debugging.  The devolve debugger stopped on line 19 and disabled the breakpoint on line 21!

See attached screens.

Looking in the trace I see this:

"[19:33:38.490 UTC] Error on CreateBreakpoint: could not find statement at /Users/gforghetti/Projects/Golang/Golang-gforghetti/Test_Programs/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.go:21, please use a line with a statement"

[image: 3 Breakpoint set]

[image: Debu stopped at line 19, breakpoint disabled at line 21]

Answer (score 1):

Delve (vscode go's debugging backend) couldn't find a statement corresponding to the first breakpoint and started the debugging session with only the second breakpoint. If you look at the "Breakpoints" panel, you will see the first breakpoint was greyed out.

[image]

This is more visible when you enable the verbose tracing during the debugging session. (Set `"trace": "verbose"` in launch.json launch configuration and check "Go Debug" OUTPUT channel)

```
[Trace - 09:55:31.99] client -> {
  "command":"setBreakpoints",
  "arguments":{
     "source": {"name":"main.go","path":"/project/demo/main.go"},
     "lines":[10,14],"breakpoints":[{"line":10},{"line":14}],
     "sourceModified":false},
  "type":"request","seq":3}

...
[Trace - 09:55:31.101] client  <- {
  "seq":0,
  "type":"response",
  "request_seq":3,
  "success":true,
  "command":"setBreakpoints",
  "body":{
    "breakpoints":
      [
        {"verified":false,
         "message":"could not find statement at /project/demo/main.go:10, please use a line with a statement",
         "source":{}},
        {"id":2,"verified":true,
         "source": {"name":"main.go","path":"/project/demo/main.go"},"line":14}]}}
```

If you change the code to add a statement, you will be able to stop at the first breakpoint.

```
...
func main() {
    if x := runtime.GOOS; x != `darwin` { // <-- first breakpoint now valid.
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, `only runs on macOS`)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(`Hello World!`)
}
```

Tip: You can check the assembly code by selecting "Open Disassembly View" from the context menu (mouse right click) and see what code the Go compiler produces.